# XSLT Add spring bean to beans.xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I'm newbie with xslt.
I need to add spring bean to xml in case it does not exist yet.
So i tried next code (i use ant to run this code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(bean[@class='com.mysite.MyCustomController'])">
                <bean class="com.mysite.MyCustomController"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works but adds element with xmlns attribute, so it looks like this in final XML file:

```
<bean xmlns="" class="com.mysite.MyCustomController"/>
```

I expect result without xmlns attribute, so i searched and my xsl code turns to:

```
...
<xsl:if test="not(bean[@class='com.mysite.MyCustomController'])">
    <bean class="com.mysite.MyCustomController" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"/>
</xsl:if>
...
```

And now result XML looks fine:

```
<bean class="com.mysite.MyCustomController"/>
```

but! **IF condition does not work**. It adds same bean each time i run code.

Is my xsl wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:bn="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:attribute-set name="bean-attr-list">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">com.mysite.MyCustomController</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(bn:bean[@class='com.mysite.MyCustomController'])">
                <xsl:element name="bean" namespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" use-attribute-sets="bean-attr-list" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XML contains the elements in the namespace `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans`. You check and add elements to the default namespace (""). To make things work, you need to modify your code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:bn="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  exclude-result-prefixes="bn">
  ..........
     <xsl:if test="not(bn:bean[@class='com.mysite.MyCustomController'])">
       <bean class="com.mysite.MyCustomController"
             xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"/>
     </xsl:if>
  .............
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "IF" works. But this xsl adds bean as: <bean xmlns:bn="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         class="com.mysite.MyCustomController"/>. Is it possible to add without xmlns attribute?

Comment: @Alexandr83 Add to xsl:stylesheet element `exclude-result-prefixes="bn"`